# How to combine 2 columns of sql results into 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pretty stumped on this one.  I am getting two columns of sql results for emplid but don't know how to just combine them into 1.  Anyone know how?  I'm using oracle. Here is the sql:

```
SELECT ee.emplid, mem.emplid
  FROM ps_employees ee, ps_vc_plan_mem mem
 WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
       AND ee.emplid NOT IN (SELECT vc.emplid
                               FROM ps_vc_plan_mem vc
                              WHERE vc.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP'))
       AND ee.emplid IN
              (SELECT srv.emplid
                 FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
                WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                      AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                      AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
   OR mem.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
```

Comment: Do you want to combine them, or only show one of them? You can concatenate strings using the `||` operator in Oracle. If you only want one of the fields, remove the one you don't want from your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I want to combine the results into 1 column..so if there are 10 results in 1 column and 35 in the other, I want one column of 45 results

Comment: I don't see a join between the two tables you're querying. Are you trying to get the `ee` records that match the filters, and everything from `mem`?

Comment: so a sum()?  Little confused...I don't see any where clause that actually links mem and ee together.  Is the cross join intentional?

Comment: If ee.emplid has 10 results and mem.emplid returns the same 10 results then do you want 10 rows or 20 with duplicates?

Comment: I get two columns of emplids...I want to combine both of those columns into 1..

Comment: @TMNT2014, but the second 10 results are different

Comment: Do you want *any* duplicates; your current logic stops any `ee.emplid` values that are also `mem.emplid` values because of the `not in` clause; but can you have duplicates within the `ee` or `mem` lists on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following the logic you just want to split your current cross-join out into separate queries and union the results together; and you can lose one of the filters along the way as it's redundant:

```
SELECT ee.emplid,
  FROM ps_employees ee
 WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
       AND ee.emplid IN
              (SELECT srv.emplid
                 FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
                WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                      AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                      AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
UNION ALL
SELECT mem.emplid
  FROM ps_vc_plan_mem mem
 WHERE mem.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
```

The `union` eliminates duplicates, so you don't need to explicitly exclude values from the first half that appear in the second half.

If either part of the query can produce duplicates on its own - the same `ee.emplid` can appear twice, say - then this will suppress those duplicates too. If they can exist and you want to show them then you'd need to use `union all` instead, and you might in that case want to reinstate the `not exists` clause.

[Read more about the `union` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries004.htm).

If you wanted an overall count then you could wrap this as an inline view:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT ee.emplid,
      FROM ps_employees ee
     WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
           AND ee.emplid IN
                  (SELECT srv.emplid
                     FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
                    WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                          AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                          AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT mem.emplid
      FROM ps_vc_plan_mem mem
     WHERE mem.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
)
```

Comment: Perfect!  How would I then do a COUNT() on the results that returns?

Comment: @user3586248 - you can use an inline view to achieve that; added an example.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you want a `UNION`, which is one result set (the first column) concatenated with another result set (the second column). It would look something like this:

```
SELECT ee.emplid
FROM ps_employees ee, ps_vc_plan_mem mem
WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
AND ee.emplid NOT IN (SELECT vc.emplid
                           FROM ps_vc_plan_mem vc
                          WHERE vc.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP'))
AND ee.emplid IN
          (SELECT srv.emplid
             FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
            WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                  AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                  AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
OR mem.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
--Here's the use of UNION
UNION ALL
--Seond query is the same, just returning the "other" column
SELECT mem.emplid
FROM ps_employees ee, ps_vc_plan_mem mem
WHERE     ee.empl_status IN ('A', 'L')
AND ee.emplid NOT IN (SELECT vc.emplid
                           FROM ps_vc_plan_mem vc
                          WHERE vc.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP'))
AND ee.emplid IN
          (SELECT srv.emplid
             FROM ps_Z_ADD_EMP_SRVDT srv
            WHERE     srv.emplid = ee.emplid
                  AND srv.z_serv_dt_type = 'ESP'
                  AND service_dt <= (SELECT asofdate FROM psasofdate))
OR mem.vc_plan_id in ('PNC-RS','PNC-SO','PNC-ESPP')
```

If you want your result to be distinct values, use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, but other than that, you're pretty much set.

Comment: Yes UNION is what I was looking for.